# List view remains blank even after creating a record in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I have been working with odoo for quite sometimes and I have never experienced this issue before, The tree view of a model is not displaying records even after they have been created.

This is my model:

```py
class PayrollStructureByJob(models.Model):
    _name = 'payroll.job'
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'
    _description = 'Salary Structure By job Position'
    _rec_name = 'job_id'

    job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string='Job Position')
    salary_id = fields.Many2one('hr.payroll.structure',
                                string='Salary Structure')
    wage = fields.Float()
    notes = fields.Text()
    active = fields.Boolean()
```

This is my record rule I added to the security file, I created for the model:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_payroll_job,payroll_job,model_payroll_job,hr.group_hr_manager,1,1,1,1
access_payroll_job_base,payroll_job_base,model_payroll_job,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
```

This is my tree view and my form view:

```
<record id="view_payroll_job_list" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">view.payroll.job.list</field>
      <field name="model">payroll.job</field>
       <field eval="8" name="priority"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="id"/>
          <field name="job_id"/>
          <field name="salary_id"/>
          <field name="wage"/>
          <field name="active"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>


    <record id="view_payroll_job_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.payroll.job.form</field>
        <field name="model">payroll.job</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           
            <form>
              <sheet>
                <group>
                <field name="id"/>
                  <field name="job_id"/>
                  <field name="salary_id"/>
                  <field name="wage"/>
                  <field name="notes"/>
                  <field name="active"/>
                </group>
              </sheet>
              <div class="oe_chatter">
                <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    
                <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
            </div>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I am confused as too what could be wrong, I may not have caught something but I can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object has a field named `active`, odoo will filter out all inactive records unless they were explicitly asked for (setting `active_test` to `True` in the context).

You defined the `active` field with a default value set to `False`, Odoo will add the `('active', '=', 1)` triplet to the search domain which will filter out all records with `active` set to `False`. If you keep the default value for active field, the created records will not be visible in the tree view.

You can find many examples in Odoo defining the active field like following:

```
active = fields.Boolean(default=True, help="Set active to false to hide the Account Tag without removing it.")
```

Comment: Wow it works, weird odoo will do something like that, they could have just made the field name a reserved field name like ID, so we don't get to use it. Thank you so much, I was beginning to think something was wrong with me.